# Disabling password change for a MySQL user

Tags: mysql, permissions, users

Is it possible for MySQL users to prevent/disable changing their password with just the USAGE option? There are no global permissions allowed. 
I tried to google, but had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this could be by using [pluggable authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pluggable-authentication.html). This way the password is stored externally and therefore can't be changed from within mysql. This allows you to use PAM, LDAP or other authentication services.

For [PAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pam-pluggable-authentication.html), assuming you have configured PAM already in your OS (assuming Linux below), then in MySQL do:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN authentication_pam SONAME 'authentication_pam.so';
CREATE USER bob@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH authentication_pam AS 'mysql';
```

... where `AS 'mysql'` refers to a file `/etc/pam.d/mysql`.

If the user then tries to set their password (I've tested this only on MariaDB with the unix_socket plugin):

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('My_very_clever_password');
```

... that query will "work", however it gives a warning:

> SET PASSWORD has no significance for users authenticating via plugins

Answer (score 1):

## Recompiling

If you absolutely need this, you should be able to recompile MySQL, setting all instances in [`sql_authentication.cc`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/f5ed5d58ffae0ff4c668830376faa411987915a1/sql/auth/sql_authentication.cc) changing `AUTH_FLAG_USES_INTERNAL_STORAGE` to `AUTH_FLAG_PRIVILEGED_USER_FOR_PASSWORD_CHANGE`. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by setting the `read_only` parameter on my server. This would take action on every non super-user though, so it may not be ideal for all situations.

Comment: Hey @Kyle, can you be more specific on your solution? Did you alter the MySQL User table to readonly or what did you do in detail? Thanks!